# Python error when doing list comprehension

Tags: python, list, dictionary, xpath, list-comprehension

I've got a list of dictionaries with a xpath query from a HTML file.
It is something like this:

```
[{"not-interested-in":"", "url": url_string1},
 {"not-interested-in":"", "url": url_string2}, and so on...]
```

Now I try to obtain a new list with all the values of the "url" key from all the dictionaries:

```
[url_string1, url_string2, ...]
```

I tried list comprehension as it was the most recommended method, and I did this(**data** is the list of dictionaries):

```
data = tree.xpath('(//li[@data-bns="API"]/@data)[position() <= 5]')
imageURLs = [di['url'] for di in data]
```

When running, I got an error message something like this:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Can anybody help me, please?

Comment: Your actual code would help

Comment: When you print `data`, what do you get?

Comment: @zondo Ok, I actually get somethng like this: 
[ '{ }', '{ }' ]

My bad, didn't notice

Answer (score 0):

In `imageURLs = [di['url'] for di in data]` you're trying to index into an object (`di`, which is a string), using another string (`'url'`) as your index. Strings don't support string indexing!

(E.g. `'Hello!'['a']` will return the same error.)

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking the object **di** is a dictionary instance